Use a here-document to create a script for AWK
Why doesn't this work?
#!/bin/bash
DOMAIN="example.com"
PING_COUNT=3
#prints column header
awk 'BEGIN {printf("%-8s %-8s %-8s %-8s %s\n", "avg", "min", "max", "mdev", "hostname")}'
FORMAT_RESULTS=$(cat << EOF
'{
        split($0, line, " = ")
        split(line[1], temp)
        hostname = temp[2]
        split(line[2], temp)
        split(temp[1], stats, "/")
        min = stats[1]
        avg = stats[2]
        max = stats[3]
        mdev = stats[4]
        printf("%-8s %-8s %-8s %-8s %s\n", avg, min, max, mdev, hostname)
}'
EOF
)


for server in $(dig +short -t SRV _kerberos._tcp.dc._msdcs.$DOMAIN | awk '{ print substr( $4, 1, length($4)-1 ) }'); do
        PING=$(ping -c $PING_COUNT -q -n $server)
        #uncomment the following line for debug purposes
        #echo $PING >> unformatted_ping_results.txt
        echo $PING | awk "$FORMAT_RESULTS"
done

But this does
#!/bin/bash
DOMAIN="example.com"
PING_COUNT=3
#prints column header
awk 'BEGIN {printf("%-8s %-8s %-8s %-8s %s\n", "avg", "min", "max", "mdev", "hostname")}'

for server in $(dig +short -t SRV _kerberos._tcp.dc._msdcs.$DOMAIN | awk '{ print substr( $4, 1, length($4)-1 ) }'); do
        PING=$(ping -c $PING_COUNT -q -n $server)
        #uncomment the following line for debug purposes
        #echo $PING >> unformatted_ping_results.txt
        echo $PING | awk '{
        split($0, line, " = ")
        split(line[1], temp)
        hostname = temp[2]
        split(line[2], temp)
        split(temp[1], stats, "/")
        min = stats[1]
        avg = stats[2]
        max = stats[3]
        mdev = stats[4]
        printf("%-8s %-8s %-8s %-8s %s\n", avg, min, max, mdev, hostname)
        }'
done

Awk always complains about awk invalid char ''' in expression with the first example but doesn't for the second.
I thought it was basically the same thing, just a cleaner way of doing things. I know I could also just create an file for awk, but sometimes I need to contain everything in a single file.

Please try to debug your problem before you post a question.  Debugging includes simplifying.  For example, your for loops appear to be identical, so that’s not the difference — so just do for server in foo.example.com, or, better yet, just set server=foo.example.com and eliminate the loop.  Eliminate $PING and just pipe ping into awk. … (Cont’d)

(Cont’d) …  You’re testing with a twelve-line Awk script in a variable (ten lines plus braces).  Cut that down to just a few lines.   And running the script in verbose mode is an obvious step.

It doesn't work because the script you're passing to awk as awk "$FORMAT_RESULTS" contains quotes (as opposed to awk 'script' where the quotes delimit script rather than being part of it) but storing code in a variable is never a cleaner way of doing anything. Variables are for data, functions are for code. Just define a shell function that calls awk and then call that function wherever you like, you don't need to put the awk script in another file, e.g.
#!/bin/bash
DOMAIN="example.com"
PING_COUNT=3
#prints column header
awk 'BEGIN {printf("%-8s %-8s %-8s %-8s %s\n", "avg", "min", "max", "mdev", "hostname")}'
format_results() {
    awk '{
        split($0, line, " = ")
        split(line[1], temp)
        hostname = temp[2]
        split(line[2], temp)
        split(temp[1], stats, "/")
        min = stats[1]
        avg = stats[2]
        max = stats[3]
        mdev = stats[4]
        printf("%-8s %-8s %-8s %-8s %s\n", avg, min, max, mdev, hostname)
    }'
}   

for server in $(dig +short -t SRV _kerberos._tcp.dc._msdcs.$DOMAIN | awk '{ print substr( $4, 1, length($4)-1 ) }'); do
        PING=$(ping -c $PING_COUNT -q -n $server)
        #uncomment the following line for debug purposes
        #echo $PING >> unformatted_ping_results.txt
        echo $PING | format_results
done

The above is untested and with other issues left as-is - run your code through http://shellcheck.net and fix what it tells you about as a starting point but I'd expect your code to at least look more like this so you aren't using all upper case variable names when you shouldn't be, your shell variables are quoted correctly, and so you only call awk once outside of the loop instead of once per iteration through the loop:
#!/usr/bin/env bash

domain='example.com'
ping_count=3

for server in $(dig +short -t SRV _kerberos._tcp.dc._msdcs."$domain" | awk '{ print substr( $4, 1, length($4)-1 ) }'); do
    ping_output=$(ping -c "$ping_count" -q -n "$server")
    #uncomment the following line for debug purposes
    #echo "$ping_output" >> unformatted_ping_results.txt
    echo "$ping_output"
done |
awk '
    BEGIN {
        #prints column header
        printf "%-8s %-8s %-8s %-8s %s\n", "avg", "min", "max", "mdev", "hostname"
    }
    {
        split($0, line, " = ")
        split(line[1], temp)
        hostname = temp[2]
        split(line[2], temp)
        split(temp[1], stats, "/")
        min = stats[1]
        avg = stats[2]
        max = stats[3]
        mdev = stats[4]
        printf "%-8s %-8s %-8s %-8s %s\n", avg, min, max, mdev, hostname
    }
'


Thanks for all of the suggestions! I've put it into it's own function and am going to start using shellcheck. The problem with only calling awk once in my script is that you have to wait for all of the servers to be tested before seeing any results, which could take a long time and doesn't offer any visual queues that anything is happening. I like the idea though.

You're welcome. awk will get the output as it's being generated, a pipe doesn't wait for the command on the left of it to finish before passing along the output to the command on the right of it, it's passed along while running. If you're not seeing output as quickly as you expect it may be a buffering issued. Add ; fflush() after the 2nd print in the awk script to see if that helps.

If you want to see a progress indicator you could add echo '.' >&2 or similar inside the shell loop.

I think the problem is that you are making literal single quotes part of the awk program.
There's really no benefit to using a HEREDOC as you have; it offers zero utility and is just introducing problems.
You might have more success like so:
FORMAT_RESULTS='{
        split($0, line, " = ")
        split(line[1], temp)
        hostname = temp[2]
        split(line[2], temp)
        split(temp[1], stats, "/")
        min = stats[1]
        avg = stats[2]
        max = stats[3]
        mdev = stats[4]
        printf("%-8s %-8s %-8s %-8s %s\n", avg, min, max, mdev, hostname)
}'

